# Firebase where to use "orderByChild" method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase and I need to sort data by the username but the problem that I'am using these method below and I couldn't understand where can I use the "orderByChild" method:

Here's my json (I have edited manually for hiding some secret data's):

```js
"Following" : {
    "ORBBKfZAAUhqI1h7ojQDzYOjgkp1" : { 
       "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1": true,
      //Now I am showing the posts for following users only
      //And I need to sort posts by Username so where can 
      //I user orderByChild method to sort from "A" to "Z"
  },
  "Posts" : {
    "-KduqnVVczZf5uibQiZ-" : {
      "Describe" : "hello1",
      "Time" : 14881230655,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Dom"
    },
    "-Ke5gJ00CxbjhOuhzLIx" : {
      "Describe" : "hello2",
      "Time" : 1488318465,
      "UID" : "pypD1SYZkbcYesk09WuMUY1AkTf1",
      "Username" : "Jice"
    },
    "-KeCuiFmUCpN19zwsTsR" : {
      "Describe" : "hello3",
      "Time" : 1488439652,
      "UID" : "z2SNUlLd6mQM8nnlkU2VUws5Ggl2",
      "Username" : "Ali"
    },
}
```

And here's my class method:

```
mDatabaseFriends.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(final DataSnapshot following : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Query ZZ = mDatabase.orderByChild("UID").equalTo(following.getKey());
                ZZ.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        mAdapter.add(mAdapter.mdataSet.size(),dataSnapshot.getValue(Getting_Posts.class));}
```

Waiting for some help brothers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase where to use orderByChild method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749461/firebase-where-to-use-orderbychild-method)

Comment: I have deleted now.

Comment: Don't repost an existing question please. Repeatedly doing so may get you banned from Stack Overflow. The best way to ensure you get help is to have a [minimal, complete reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question (read the link, it is quite useful). In your current question, we have no way to know what `mDatabaseFriends` and `mDatabase` refer to.